# Passing sas variable into a sql pass through statement

Tags: sql, sas

Using SAS I'm pulling data from a SQL data base using a pass through for speed as the DB's are quite large. The below code works as expected.

```
%let expectdate1 = '2013-07-03';*/

proc sql;

connect to ***** as abc (tdpid=***** user='****' password='*****' );
create table Searched_data as
select * from connection to dss(

SELECT  *
FROM  database.tablename
WHERE CAPTURE_DT >= '2013-07-01' and CAPTURE_DT <= &expectdate1

);
disconnect from abc;
quit;
```

The issues arises when I wan to have expectate1 parameterised.

so I replace

```
%let expectdate1 = '2013-07-03';*/
```

with

```
%let expectdate1 = put(Date(),YYMMDD10.);
```

This doesnt work and the error Im getting is something like

```
....WHERE CAPTURE_DT >= '2013-07-01' and CAPTURE_DT <= put(Date(),YYMMDD10) .....
```

So its not evaluating my date code and instead its passing the actual code to SQL and not the resultant string.

Answer (score 4):

Shorack is correct that the PUT statement can not be used with %SYSFUNC, however you can use PUTN successfully.

You should simply need the following.

```
%LET EXPECTDATE1 = %SYSFUNC(PUTN(%SYSFUNC(DATE()),YYMMDD10.));

%put EXPECTDATE1=&EXPECTDATE1.;
```

SASLOG:

```
EXPECTDATE1=2013-08-05
```

Comment: That is the thing I love about SAS.  No matter how much I think I know, there is always something that I don't.

Comment: hmm still doesn't work.
The log shows EXPECTDATE1=2013-08-06
Yet its not returning any results, if I write 
%let expectdate1 = '2013-08-06';
Then it works fine.

Comment: Because, if it needs to be quoted, you need to add those quotes to the macro variable. i.e: %LET EXPECTDATE1 = %str(%')'%SYSFUNC(PUTN(%SYSFUNC(DATE()),YYMMDD10.))%str(%');

Comment: %LET EXPECTDATE1 = %bquote('%SYSFUNC(PUTN(%SYSFUNC(DATE()),YYMMDD10.))');

%put EXPECTDATE1=&EXPECTDATE1.;

Comment: Can you confirm if you are testing this in a pass through scenario like in my original post? as it works fine when not in a pass through.

Answer (score 2):

Note: edited for the single quotes you need.

Let me first provide a solution that works, then explain why your approach does not work.
Use this piece of code instead:

```
data _NULL_;
    call symput("expectdate1",cats("'",put(Date(),YYMMDD10.)),"'");
run;
```

The above piece of code will create your string and then put it into the expectdate1 macro variable.

**So, why was your code not working?**
That is because you do not make a distinction between SAS functions and SAS macro functions.
put(Date(),YYMMDD10.) are not macro functions (easily distinguished because they start with a percentage sign. -> % <-)

So SAS Macro does not evaluate it and just puts the piece of code into your SQL statement, literally.

Now there is something called the %sysfunc function. It is a macro function that will perform the enclosed normal function.
So %sysfunc(Date()) would be resolved by SAS macro before setting the macro variable expectdate. 
Note that each function needs to be enclosed by the %sysfunc function, i.e.,

```
%let someVariable = %sysfunc(mean(max(1,3),5)); /*WRONG*/
%let someVariable = %sysfunc(mean(%sysfunc(max(1,3)),5)); /*RIGHT*/
```

That being said, it does not work for some SAS functions and put is one of them.
 That is why i provided the solution on top: use a data step to prepare it any way you like and write the result into a macro variable.

Comment: The code does not work, log still shows 

 `WHERE CAPTURE_DT >= '2013-08-05' and CAPTURE_DT <= &expectdate1`

and no results are returned

Comment: Updated answer to reflect your need for single quotes. Why it does not resolve, that i don't know. Here it works just fine in a brand new session. It could help to make your logging more verbose to figure out what is happening. (symbolgen mprint mprintnest mlogic mlogicnest)

Comment: Can you confirm if you are testing this in a pass through scenario like in my original post? as it works fine when not in a pass through.

Comment: Ok got it working now, thanks!... the extra debugging helped. It showed it was sending &expectdate1. but then went on to explain that it was resolved to the correct value.